createRoot React 18 causes multiple renders/execution
Whenever i try to execute this code in react 18 it renders more that once however on react 17 it executes once and works just fine.
How can i get the following code to only execute once? Or is there something causing multiple executions?
import React from "react";
import "./index.css";

import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client"; // Import createRoot from react-dom/client


import App from "./App";
import { store } from "./store/store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";

const root = document.getElementById("root");

const renderApp = () => {
  createRoot(root).render( // Use createRoot from react-dom/client
    <React.StrictMode>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
};

renderApp();

serviceWorker.register();


Does this question and its accepted answer answer your question?

@Palladium02 Im still reading the answers to the link. I see its not a bug but a way to improve coding standards

This is a feature, not a bug, check https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode.
In order to fix it:

if it actually creates a bug in your app, it's probably because one of your components has side effects during render, make sure to not do that and the bug will be fixed,
if you don't actually have a bug visible by the users of your app, just ignore the double render, it's not a bug,
if it creates performance issues, check that the performance issues are still there when you build for production (the double render happens only in development).


Ok. I've gathered that it's not a bug but it still affects me cause in some parts of the code it ends up rendering multiple doms - if that makes sense.
